# Call create method of other model

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I have two models, i need to create record in `survey.page` model from `survey.survey` model (on hitting the save button). The method i have tried is not working. Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

```
class Survey(models.Model):
_name = 'survey.survey'
   @api.multi
    def my_func(self):
        last_id = self.env['survey.survey'].search([])[-1].id
        vals = {'title': 'Page 1', 'survey_id': last_id}
        other_object = self.env['survey.page']
        return other_object.create(vals)


class SurveyPage(models.Model):
    _name = 'survey.page'

    title = fields.Char('Page Title', required=True, translate=True)
    survey_id = fields.Many2one('survey.survey', string='Survey', ondelete='cascade', required=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using overwrite `create` method of `survey.survey` model.
Try Blow code:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    _name = 'survey.survey'
    @api.multi
    def my_func(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        vals = {'title': 'Page 1', 'survey_id': self.id}
        other_object = self.env['survey.page']
        return other_object.create(vals)

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
       res = super(Survey, self).create(vals)
       res.my_func()
       return res

class SurveyPage(models.Model):
    _name = 'survey.page'

    title = fields.Char('Page Title', required=True, translate=True)
    survey_id = fields.Many2one('survey.survey', string='Survey', ondelete='cascade', required=True)
```

Comment: I understand. Works like a champ. Thanks